# How should I write words with dash in camelCase?

Tags: objective-c, camelcasing, code-standards

For example: [Meta-information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-information)

`metaInfornation`, `metainformation` or `metainfo`?

`getMetainfo`, `getMetaInfo` or `getMetaInformation`?

what about objective-c style?

Comment: "get" should not be used as a method prefix outside of very special cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am personally a fan of camelCase and no abbreviations. So I would use `metaInformation`. `metaInfo` is also good because it's a very common abbreviation.
What I dislike is something like `printAttr` or similar.

Apple has [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) on that topic describing the conventions.

*Note that you should **not** use `get` in your getter!*

When you apply these conventions you have many opportunities (e.g. [Key-Value-Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a property, then you'd want to use `metaInformation` or `metaInfo`, and it will generate the getter as `-metaInformation` or `-metaInfo`. Never use get in a method name.

Comment: Uppercase `I` is the one to choose ;)

Comment: @max_ From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html): `If the method returns an attribute of the receiver, name the method after the attribute. The use of “get” is unnecessary, unless one or more values are returned indirectly.`

Comment: Yes, everything is clear about "get" in obj-c :), I gave generalized example, thanks! I was more interested in choice of upper or lower case next to dash.